# How to draw an arrow in the legend box using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add an arrow outside the box of a plot, replacing the values in a gradient-scaled legend. By doing that I hope to make it simpler to understand my legend. Some toy data:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(27)

df <- data.frame(food =  c("apple","meat","rice","beans","sandwich","potato","bublegum","candy","pasta","grape",                 "lemon","orange"),
                 tastefullness_according_to_kids =  c("03","06","02","10","05","12","01","04","08","07","11","09"),
                 votes = sample.int(50, 12))

df$tastefullness_according_to_kids <- as.numeric(df$tastefullness_according_to_kids)
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=food, y=votes, fill = tastefullness_according_to_kids))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low= "#000000", high="#FF0000", labels=NULL)+
  xlab(expression(symbol('\255')))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=30))
```

My problem here is that although I succeeded to insert an arrow in the x-axis (or even in the y-axis), I am unable to insert it in the legend, next to the fill scale. What I want to accomplish is this:

[image: Expected result]

I also tried the same code as above, but replacing the "xlab" by "labs", in order to insert my arrow next to the legend, but it hasn't worked.

Could anyone help me with that? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replace the default breaks / labels in the fill legend with a single break at the desired location for the arrow (I used 6.5) and provide a unicode arrow as the label. After that, hide ticks from the legend and adjust the font size for the arrow to suit your needs:

```
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(x=food, y=votes, fill = tastefullness_according_to_kids))+
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Tastefulness\naccording\nto kids",
                      low= "#000000", high="#FF0000", 
                      breaks = 6.5, labels = "\u2191",
                      guide = guide_colorbar(label.theme = element_text(size = 50),
                                             ticks = FALSE))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=30))
```

[image: plot with arrow]

Comment: Thank you, @Z.Lin! Would It be possible to bring the arrow closer to the scale in the legend?

Comment: I'm away from computer now, but since the arrow is essentially a legend label, adjusting the `hjust` parameter in `guide_colorbar(label.theme = element_text(...))` should do the job.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, but that's ok. I'll leave it as it is. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One hacky option would be to use `cowplot` to extract the legend, add your arrow via `annotation_custom` and afterwards glue it back to your main plot via `patchwork`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(
  x = food, y = votes,
  fill = tastefullness_according_to_kids
)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#000000", high = "#FF0000", labels = NULL) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 30))

legend <- cowplot::get_legend(p) |> cowplot::ggdraw()

legend <- legend + annotation_custom(
  grob = grid::textGrob(expression(symbol("\255")),
    gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 50),
    x = unit(.325, "npc"),
    y = unit(.475, "npc")
  )
)

p <- p + guides(fill = "none")

library(patchwork)

p + legend +
  plot_layout(widths = c(8, 2))
```

[image]